# Download files from specific folder in AIX box

Tags: ftp, aix

I have an AIX box. I wanted to connect to remote FTP server and download a specified folder "abc".

I have created a script; but it isn't working.

Here is my Code:

```
#!/bin/sh HOST='ftp.abc.xysz.net' USER='ftp' PASSWD='password' FILE='ababababababababababababab.abab'; 
ftp $HOST user $USER $PASSWD mget $FILE 
quit END_SCRIPT 
exit 0
```

Here is the error I receive when I execute Script..

[image]

Anyone has any idea to download the files from remote FTP server. Is there any single command available

Comment: NO Single command, as login security and authentication, are key part in remote FTP, once you are crossed to that then this looks possible else no..

Comment: thats absolutely true. I just checking if there is any way.. Either my script is failing.. Below is the script..

Comment: #!/bin/sh

HOST='ftp.abc.xysz.net'
USER='ftp'
PASSWD='password'
FILE='ftp://ababababababababababababab.abab'

ftp $HOST  
user $USER
$PASSWD
mget $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0

Comment: you need to check handshake! once it is authenticated and connected you are good to execute, `mget $file`; I am not much of linux guy so will not misguide on command please google for that :) also place that code in question to get better answers(I have done that this time)..

Comment: MarmiK,  I have pasted the error message. I bellieve authentication is fine. otherwise it had prompted for that.. Even the username is correct. (Basically the server where I am trying to connect, I can even connect anonymous !! ;))

Comment: do you really have `#!/bin/sh (and) HOST=....` all on the same line? That won't work. If you want a script, the first line must be the "shebang", i.e. `#!/bin/sh` and then the remaining script must be on the following lines. Shell one-liners are highly overrated, and in this case, if you can get it to work on one line, it will be 10X harder to understand by someone 6 months from now who has to maintain it. Did you search here for `[bash] ftp here document` (or similar spellings of HERE-DOC, EOF, EOD, EOS)? Your use case is a very common problem here on S.O. Good luck.

Comment: yes @shelter it is not on same line. its there on different line. and I have not used EOF as I was not aware of its usage. I'll try sometime using that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script doesn't look properly formatted... it would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

HOST='10.129.151.41'
USER='technicolor'
PASSWD='blueray'
FILE='ababababababababababababab.abab'

ftp -n <<END_SCRIPT
open $HOST
user $USER $PASSWD
get $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Comment: Thanks you guys.

Below script worked for me :-
HOST='10.129.151.41'
USER='technicolor'
PASSWD='blueray'
FILE='ababababababababababababab.abab'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
user $USER $PASSWD
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
mget $FILE
echo "YES"
quit
END_SCRIPT